# How to ignore invalid name in publish to npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, nrwl-nx, verdaccio

I need to publish package to my local npm (using verdaccio)

the package called: `@myorg/database/auth`. But npm throw error:

```
npm ERR! Invalid name: "@myorg/database/auth"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Error: Command failed: npm publish --tag latest --access public --registry=https://verdaccio-dev.myorg.io
```

I must using that name. is there an option to ignore or workaround solution?

The name of the package is generated by [nrwl/nx](https://nx.dev/). so I can't change that because it will change the entire project structure.

What can I do?

Comment: I'd say that the problem is the second slash. Names must contain only URL-safe characters although you can define a scoped package in the form of `@scope/package_name`

Comment: And what can I do? I have this name because I'm using nx project and the build generate this name for me. I can't change that.

Comment: I've never used that but I assume there should be a way to set the name you want to the project

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the issue is that you are generating the library with code like this:

```
nx generate @nrwl/node:library --name=auth --directory=database
```

...and you are running (or planning to run) code like this:

```
import { databaseAuth } from '@myorg/database/auth';
```

According to [their documentation](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/structure/buildable-and-publishable-libraries#publishable-libraries), `nx` does not select the library name. Rather it is incumbent upon the developer to choose a valid name.

> One particularity when generating a library with --publishable is that it requires you to also provide an --importPath. Your import path is the actual scope of your distributable package (e.g.: @myorg/mylib) - which needs to be a valid npm package name.

So, if you ran this:

```
nx generate @nrwl/node:library -name=auth --directory=database --importPath=@myorg/my-cool-db --publishable
```

...you should be able to publish your package as `@myorg/my-cool-db`. But if you specified `--importPath=@myorg/database/auth` or something like that (with a second slash), I imagine that's the source of the trouble and you'll want to change the `importPath` value.